# SSH connect to amazon server using php

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, ssh

I need my php site to access a remote amazon server and execute a script remotely, returning it's output.

So i've searched for a solution, I downloaded [php seclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) and wrote this PHP code:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$key = new Crypt_RSA();

$key->loadKey(file_get_contents('SRF.pem'));

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com');
if (!$ssh->login('ec2-user', $key)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
else
    exit('Good');
?>
```

Problem is: the php returns "Login Failed".

The pem file has read permissions (**sudo chown 0400 SRF.pem**) and it's located in the same directory of the PHP file above, and I also succeed connecting remotely to the server using linux shell(but i need it to work on PHP). I mean, succeeded connecting doing this:

```
ssh -i SRF.pem ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com -o LocalCommand="sudo su"
```

So my guess is that something is wrong with the php functions/syntax i've used, but what?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried with the native SSH2 libraries?

Comment: Add a /SRF.pem instead of just SRF.pem and then try if it works

Comment: Tried /SRF.pem. still the same..

Comment: One last thing can you change the permission on the pem file to 444 and then try? There is no any issue to your PHP code.